# Newline (<br>) between radio choices in Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, twig, newline, symfony-forms

I have this form generation code..:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
            ->add('mode', 'choice', array(
                'label' => false,
                'choices' => array(
                  'mode1' => '1',
                  'mode2' => '2',
                  'mode3' => '3',
                ),
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'required' => true,
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

The problem is that rendered form has choices (radio inputs) inline, without `<br/>` tags between them.

Also, i cannot find how do i render form with a twig template so do not touch PHP code, for example, how can i specially 'decorate' **each** choice in my radio buttons list.

```
 <div style='margin:25px'>
            {{ form_start(form_options) }}
            {{ form_widget(form_options) }}
            {{ form_end(form_options) }}
        </div>
```

How can i extend this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render each form field as you like. Do not use  `{{ form_widget(form_options) }}` use `{{ form_row (form.fieldName) }}` then you can add html and style as you like : This is an exemple :

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
<label class="checkbox-inline col-md-6">
    <div class="checker" id="uniform-inlineCheckbox21">
        <span class="">
            {{form_row(form.fieldName)}}
        </span>
    </div> 
    fieldName
</label>
```

You can also pass a list of object and create manually your input :

```
{% for language in languages %}
<div class="checkbox-list">
    <label class="checkbox-inline col-md-6">
        <div class="checker" id="uniform-inlineCheckbox21">
            <span class="">
                <input type="checkbox"  name="langues[]" id="course{{loop.index}}" value="{{language.id}}" data-title="{{language.designation}}">
            </span>
        </div> 
        {{language.designation}}
    </label>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Last solution you can use form_theme and override the choices widget user by symfony :
http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thank you, but {{form_row}} handles a choice list not choices individually so i have no idea how to separate choices with newlines.

Comment: do you know how can i move checkboxes of my choices to left side of label, not right one by default?

Comment: I think this is a matter of css you can add style=" text-align: left;" into your label

Answer (score 2):

### Quickest Solution

Add this to your CSS:

```
label:after { content:"\a"; white-space:pre; }
```

### Dirty Solution

Render each radiobutton in Twig individually like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.formField.0) }}{{ form_label(form.formField.0) }}<br>
{{ form_widget(form.formField.1) }}{{ form_label(form.formField.1) }}
```

### Professional Solution

Customize the form theme, as explained at https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
Drawback: If Symfony's default theme changes in the future, you will miss it, since you're overriding it.