# Symfony - CSS Checkbox and Label in list

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I use **Symfony 2.3**, to generate form with list of checkbox with label.

```
<form method='post' action=''>
    {{ form_errors(myForm) }}
    {{ form_widget(myForm.reasons) }}
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want add checkbox in label balise or find the CSS style to add checkbox/label inline with break to line for the second element.

**I have this:**

[image]

**I want this:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use :

```
{{ form_widget(myForm.reasons, {'attr': {'class': 'task_field'}}) }}
```

to add a class name then manipulate it using CSS

[Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/rendering.html)

or you can target input with input[type='checkbox'] { //your css here  }

---

also check the answer in [Newline (<br>) between radio choices in Symfony form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370381/newline-br-between-radio-choices-in-symfony-form)